# Как правильно передать значение параметра в jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

```
{% for  project in projects_list[1:] %}
   <div class="carousel-item">
    <p>{{project.id}}</p>
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='media/images/{{project.id}}') }}" alt="Second slide">
       <div class="carousel-caption ">
        <h5>123</h5>
        <p>12323123213123123123</p>
        </div>
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Мне нужно подставлять значение id проекта в ссылку на картинку для этого проекта , но почему то браузер выдает что значение ссылки /static/media/images/%7B%7Bproject.id%7D%7D

Comment: Попробуйте `filename=f'...{project.id}'`.

Comment: Выдает ошибку jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'string', а объясняется это Raw python code is not fully supported in jinja2 template syntax.

Comment: `filename='media/images/{}'.format(project.id)`

Comment: Да спасибо помогло

Answer (score 0):

```
filename='media/images/{}'.format(project.id)
```